# How to get the xml-safe version of an sql server XML Column

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there a way to get the xml-safe version of an xml column in sql server ?

By xml-Safe i mean escaping special characters like <,>,', &, etc.

I'd like to avoid doing the replacements myself. Is there a build in function in sql server.

What I want to achieve is to store the xml content into another xml attribute.

Comment: "xml-safe" ?? What do you mean by that?? Please explain - not a commonly used expression in my opinion....

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid doing the replace myself"?  What is this "replace" you speak of?

Comment: I bet he thinks he needs to translate `<` into `&lt;`, for instance.

Comment: @Chris. I mean i don't want to REPLACE " by &quot; < by &lt;, etc

Comment: just clarified your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that by xml-safe you mean escaping of XML special tags. If you have an XML column you wish to include in another XML document then you have two options:

- project the column as `[*]`: `select ..., xmlcolumn as [*], ... from ... for xml path...` this will embed the XML content of the column in the result XMl. Eg. if the column has the value `<element>value</element>` then the result will be like `<root><row><element>value</element></row></root>`.
- project the column as the column name: `select ..., xmlcolumn, ... from ... for xml path...` this will insert the content of the column as a value (ie. it will escape it). Eg. the same value as above will produce `<root><row><xmlcolumn>&lt;element&gt;&lt;value&lt;/element&gt;`.

If your question is about something else, then you're going to have to rephrase it in a proper manner and use terms correctly. Don't invent new terms no one understands but you.

*Update*:

If you are inserting XML values into the column, then you don't have to do anything at all. The client libraries know how to handle the proper escaping. **As long as you write your code correctly**. Remeber, XML is **NOT** a string and should never, ever be treated as one. If you write XML in your client, use an appropriate XML library ([XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx), [XML DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9hbf87.aspx),  [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) etc). when passing in the XML into SQL Server, use the appropiate type: [SqlXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.aspx). Stored procedures should use the appropiate parameter type: [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx). When you read it, use the appropriate method to read XML: [GetSqlXml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlxml.aspx). Same goes for declaring the type in one of the miriad designers (LINQ to SQL , EF etc). Ultimately, there is *never* any need to escape XML characters manually. If you find yourself doing that, you're using the wrong API and you have to go back to the drawing board.

A good start reading is [XML Support in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

And finally, to manipulate XML as you describe (update XML column of table A with XML column of table B), you use [XML methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx), specifically [modify (... insert...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175466.aspx), and you bind the table B column inside the XQuery using [`sql:column`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx):

```
update A
set somecolumn.modify('insert {sql:column("B.othercolumn")} before somenode')
from A join B on ...;
```

In you comment you threat XML as a string and, as I already said, you should never ever do that: strings and XML are as water and oil.

Answer (score 16):

It is not a direct answer to this question but to anyone who tries to xml-escape strings in TSQL, here is a little function I wrote :

```
CREATE FUNCTION escapeXml 
(@xml nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @return nvarchar(4000)
    select @return = 
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(@xml,'&', '&amp;')
                ,'<', '&lt;')
            ,'>', '&gt;')
        ,'"', '&quot;')
    ,'''', '&#39;')

return @return
end
GO
```

Answer (score 9):

Another simpler way to xml escape a string is to use the following:

```
SELECT @String FOR XML PATH('')
```

e.g.

```
DECLARE @Input NVARCHAR(4000) = 'bacon & eggs'
DECLARE @String = (SELECT @Input FOR XML PATH(''))
```

then use @string from there

Comment: Nice way to convert oil to water!

Comment: And to get rid of the element wrapper use what @remusrusanu said: 
   `SELECT @String AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')`

Comment: Remarkably simple solution to a nasty problem! I have a several hundred line function and only had to add two lines at the bottom to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of an XML column are XML. By definition, that is "XML-safe".

Do you need to include XML from a column in an XML element or attribute of another XML document? Then just save the outer XML as a string in the new document.

Comment: I need to take the XML and inserted into an XML attribute. I have table A that contains an XML column and Table B that also contain an XML column. I need to get the XML from the B table and store it in an attribut of the xml content of Table A. I tried to do a "<Test xmlContent="+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), tableBxmlcontent)+"/>" but this wont work because the tableBxmlContent contains <, > etc ...