# Search and Extract a word from rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following table

Table A

```
Text,id,Cid,CName,Aid,AName
Acc.sa is very Acc.pa and Acc.ba is awesome, 1,2,AB,1,CC
Acc.aa is awesome and Acc.sas is great,2,3,CC,1,CC
Acc.ee is not only great but Acc.sew is best,4,3,FF,1,CC
```

It should fetch all the words associated with Acc so the result should be

```
 Did,id,Cid,CName,Aid,AName
 Acc.sa,1,2,AB,1,CC
 Acc.pa,1,2,AB,1,CC
 Acc.ba,1,2,AB,1,CC
 Acc.aa,2,3,CC,1,CC
 Acc.sas,2,3,CC,1,CC
 Acc.ee,4,3,FF,1,CC
 Acc.sew,4,3,FF,1,CC
```

i.e. every search should have a new row

I tried the CHARINDEX and substring but I am not sure how to proceed in SELECT statement to use CHARINDEX and substring any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a list of "acc" words that you are looking for?

Comment: anything which has acc. is my target word

Comment: You'll need to use PATINDEX with SUBSTRING inside a recursive CTE

Comment: Do you have a limit on the number of characters following the dot? Or a limit on the number of "acc" matches per line?

Comment: No limit for both cases

Comment: Your TableA says is has 6 columns but your sample data only has 4. Can you post something that is clear? Maybe a sqlfiddle? Your results are equally confusing. You list 6 columns but only show 4. As posted right now this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @SeanLange I was thinking the same thing.  Something is missing, here

Comment: Sorry for the confusion fixed the question with additional column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with base10 as (
    select n
    from (values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v(n)
), k as (
    select d2.n * 100 + d1.n * 10 + d0.n + 1 as n
    from base10 d0 cross join base10 d1 cross join base10 d2
)
select
    substring(a.Text, k.n, charindex(' ', a.Text, k.n) - k.n) as Did,
    Id, Cid, CName, Aid, AName
from TableA a inner join k
    on substring(a.Text, k.n, 4) = 'Acc.'
        and k.n < len(a.Text) /* not necessary but optimizer might use it??? */
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0f87/4 (*outputs a few extra columns*)

That will only handle strings about a thousand characters long. I suspect that's probably enough and you may even want to narrow the search length if that's slow.

I'm assuming that a space will immediately follow your "Acc." value which means it doesn't appear at the end of a line. That can be handled if necessary.

Since you're seeing errors it appears you have input lines that depart from the format you've specified. I don't see any other assumptions I'm making beyond the space character separator I mentioned.

For debugging you can replace the whole `substring()` line with this output to get a better idea of what's going on. Also add in a `where` clause to limit the rows to the ones that would cause an error:

```
select
    'Bad offset' as Msg,
    a.Text, k.n as StartOfAccBlick, charindex(' ', a.Text, k.n) as EndOfAccBlock
from ...    
where
    k.n - charindex(' ', a.Text, k.n) <= 0
```

Comment: it gives me an error message like `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'`

Comment: My bad. Fixed that problem. I fixed another column reference too.

Comment: I also fixed an off by one on the substring length.

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. I am little confused for this

Comment: Did you get the latest version of my query? I changed the `k.n` value to range from 1 to 1000 rather than 0 to 999. That's one way for that error.

Comment: `Msg 537, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`
 same error after using the latest code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98370/discussion-between-zack-and-shawnt00).

Answer (score 1):

The xml nodes method can be handy for parsing cell values into rows like this. E.g.:

```
select n.value('@s[1]', 'varchar(max)'), id, Cid, CName, Aid, AName
from Table_A ta
cross apply (select convert(xml, '<x s="' + replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(ta.[Text],'&','&amp;'),'>','&gt;'),'<','&lt;'),'''','&apos;'),'"','&quot;'),' ','"/><x s="') + '"/>') xval) r
cross apply r.xval.nodes('*') x(n)
where n.value('@s[1]', 'varchar(max)') like 'Acc.%'
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da109c/2/0)

edit - escape the 5 invalid xml chars

Comment: `Msg 9415, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
XML parsing: line 1, character 7, well formed check: no '<' in attribute value` can you please help me with this error

Comment: @Zack for those you'll need to escape them for xml, here's function from another question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17088055/99691

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a recursive CTE to substring every occurrence out. I'm pretty busy at work this morning so I can't create something matching your specific pattern but here's an example of one I've done in the past to extract all PDF file names out of a string. All the commented out lines are to show the building blocks of how I got to just the PDF file name that I needed to extract. You will need to modify the pattern search accordingly for your scenario. Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/4626).

```
DECLARE @f TABLE (fieldName VARCHAR(255), IDField int)
INSERT INTO @f VALUES('>>>>>>1.pdf test> >b>c>xyz.pdf bob >hello world.pdf foo >womp womp.pdf>', 1)
INSERT INTO @f VALUES('>2.pdf other unnecssary stuff > bar.pdf', 2)

; WITH cte2 AS (
   SELECT 
       IDField,
       --PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3 AS PDFLocation,
       --SUBSTRING(fieldName, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3)) AS PDFSubstring,
       --REVERSE(SUBSTRING(fieldName, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3))) AS PDFSubstringReverse,
       --PATINDEX('%>%', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(fieldName, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3)))) AS ReverseSymbolLocationBeforePDF,
       --LEN(SUBSTRING(fieldName, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3))) - PATINDEX('%>%', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(fieldName, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3)))) + 2 AS SymbolLocationBeforePDF,

       CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), SUBSTRING(fieldName, 
           LEN(SUBSTRING(fieldName, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3))) - PATINDEX('%>%', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(fieldName, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3)))) + 2, 
           PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3 - (LEN(SUBSTRING(fieldName, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3))) - PATINDEX('%>%', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(fieldName, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3)))) + 2) + 1
       )) AS PDFName,

       CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), STUFF(fieldName, 1, PATINDEX('%.pdf%', fieldName) + 3, '')) AS strWhatsLeft
   FROM @f

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
       IDField,
       --PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3 AS PDFLocation,
       --SUBSTRING(strWhatsLeft, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3)) AS PDFSubstring,
       --REVERSE(SUBSTRING(strWhatsLeft, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3))) AS PDFSubstringReverse,
       --PATINDEX('%>%', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(strWhatsLeft, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3)))) AS ReverseSymbolLocationBeforePDF,
       --LEN(SUBSTRING(strWhatsLeft, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3))) - PATINDEX('%>%', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(strWhatsLeft, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3)))) + 2 AS SymbolLocationBeforePDF,

       CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), SUBSTRING(strWhatsLeft, 
           LEN(SUBSTRING(strWhatsLeft, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3))) - PATINDEX('%>%', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(strWhatsLeft, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3)))) + 2, 
           PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3 - (LEN(SUBSTRING(strWhatsLeft, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3))) - PATINDEX('%>%', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(strWhatsLeft, 1, (PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3)))) + 2) + 1
       )) AS PDFName,

       CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), STUFF(strWhatsLeft, 1, PATINDEX('%.pdf%', strWhatsLeft) + 3, '')) AS strWhatsLeft
   FROM cte2
   WHERE strWhatsLeft LIKE '%.pdf%'
)

SELECT * FROM cte2 ORDER BY IDField
```